# I am trying to get data from excel sheet and pass those test data into the login & password field but I am getting following error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, data-driven-tests

**Error:**

> FAILED: cptoadsLogin
>           org.testng.TestNGException: 
>           The data provider is trying to pass 2 parameters but the method com.toads.Script.LoginDemo#cptoadsLogin takes 0
>             at org.testng.internal.Invoker.injectParameters(Invoker.java:1225)
>             at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1118)
>             at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>             at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
>             at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
>             at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
>             at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
>             at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
>             at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
>             at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
>             at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>             at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>             at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
>             at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
>             at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
>             at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>             at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:236)
>             at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:81)

**Page object:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class ToadsLogin {

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//input[@id='Username']")
    WebElement username;

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//input[@id='Password']")
    WebElement password;

    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using="//button")
    WebElement loginbtn;

    public ToadsLogin(WebDriver driver)
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void unpwd(String un,String pwd)
    {
        username.sendKeys("un");
        password.sendKeys("pwd");
    }

    public void clikonLogin()
    {
        loginbtn.click();
    }
}
```

**TestNG Script:**

```
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.toads.PoM.ToadsLogin;
import com.toads.lib.ExcelDataConfig;

public class LoginDemo extends SuperTestNG {

    @Test(dataProvider="toadsLogin")
    public void cptoadsLogin() throws Exception
    {
        ToadsLogin tlogin=new ToadsLogin(driver);
        tlogin.unpwd("un", "pwd");
        tlogin.clikonLogin();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.close();
    }


    @DataProvider(name="toadsLogin")
    public Object[][] cpToadsLogin()
    {
        ExcelDataConfig config=new ExcelDataConfig("D:\\login.xlsx");
        int rows=config.getRowCount(0);


        Object[][] data1= new Object[rows][2];
        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        {
            data1[i][0]=config.getData(0, i, 0);
            data1[i][1]=config.getData(0, i, 1);

        }
        return data1;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `dataProvider` expects method `cptoadsLogin` to get parameters.

> The data provider is trying to pass 2 parameters but the method cptoadsLogin takes 0

You need to change the method signature to receive 2 parameters

```
@Test(dataProvider = "toadsLogin")
public void cptoadsLogin(String user, String pwd) throws Exception
{
    ToadsLogin tlogin=new ToadsLogin(driver);
    tlogin.unpwd(user, pwd);
    tlogin.clikonLogin();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.close();
}
```

`user` will have the value from `data1[i][0]` and `pwd` will have the value from `data1[i][1]`

Comment: Thanks....but its also not working ,it is taking username as un and password as pwd.it is nt taking data fro excel sheet

Comment: @RakeshKumar Because this is what you put there `tlogin.unpwd("un", "pwd");` If you wand different values you need to change it.

Comment: That's what i don't have idea where exactly i need to change the script to pull the data from excel.its working fine while i am not using POM but with pom i am facing this issue with data driven testing

Comment: @RakeshKumar Just replace `"un"` and `"pwd"` with the data you want, another string or the variable holding the data. `tlogin.unpwd(str1, str2);` for example.

Comment: i want data from excel sheet.if i want data from tlogin.unpwd("un", "pwd") here then there is no problem for me.my question is how can i get data from excel sheet

Comment: @RakeshKumar I've just updated Guy's answer accordingly to your question. But Guy's comments were already really clear...